# Exclude Junit from War; Keep for Unit Tests

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a Java project that builds a war. junit-4.13.2.jar is being included in the war as a transitive dependency. I'd like to exclude the jar from the war, but I still need to have the jar for running tests.

My build.gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit'
    ...
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: "org.apache.logging.log4j", module: "log4j-core"
}
```

Using this config, I can still run my tests, but the jar still ends up in the war.

Answer (score 0):

As you already state that its because of transitive dependency from a compile/runtime dependency - the fix would be to exclude junit from the same

```
implementation ('g:a:v') {
  exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
}
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for determining which implementation I need to remove junit from? I have a lot of dependencies and I don't know which one is bringing it in. Or maybe multiple bring it in. Might there be a way to globally exclude it from the implementation?